# Customizing the Post/Page Editor in Classic Editor

Tags: css, visual-editor

I am creating custom styles for a client. While I could train her on how to apply those styles by adding code in the Text view, it would be easier if I could just create a dropdown of the styles, or add to the dropdown of H tags, she needs for the visual mode.[image] I've done several searches for a discussion on this topic, but I'm probably using the wrong terminology, so the searches are empty.

I see some plugins that seem to do that task, but they aren't up-to-date with the current WordPress version.

Comment: I'm not sure what styles and Text view you mean, can you add a screenshot showing those?

Comment: Does the addition of the screenshot help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical editor is really powerful tool which could be configured as users needs.
For configuration of WordPress additional plugin is needed: "Advanced TinyMCE Configuration"

In this page
https://bghints.blogspot.com/2023/04/customizing-classical-editor-in-wordpress.html
there is a guide and examples for configuration of plugin and respectively the Classical editor.

Using this plugin you could define new buttons and dropdowns. I assume TinyMCE allows you to add custom styles too.